# How to Share ENV Variables Among Perl Scripts

Tags: perl

I have two Perl scripts along with GIT hook script.In there i am validating the GIT  work flow.Here is the scripts calling stack.

**pre-push -> unpush-changes -> dependency-tree**

There is a for loop in unpush-changes perl script that will call the dependency-tree perl script.

**pre-push**

```
system("unpushed-changes");
  my $errorMsg = $ENV{'GIT_FLOW_ERROR_MSG'}// '';
  if($errorMsg eq "true"){
     print "Error occured!";
   }
```

**unpush-changes.pl**

```
  for my $i (0 .. $#uniqueEffectedProjectsList) {
      my $errorMsg = $ENV{'GIT_FLOW_ERROR_MSG'}// '';
      if($errorMsg ne "true"){
        my $r=system("dependency-tree $uniqueEffectedProjectsList[$i]");
     }else{
        exit 1;
     }

   }
```

**dependency-tree.pl**

```
if(system("mvn clean compile  -DskipTests")==0){
     print "successfully build"; 
     return 1;
 }else{
      $ENV{'GIT_FLOW_ERROR_MSG'} = 'true';
      print "Error occured";
      return 0;
  }
```

In my **dependency-tree** script if error occurred i have set the **ENV** variable and that will be check in the each iteration in the **unpush-changes** script.But its ENV is value empty instead of **true**. I also tried to return some value if failed and try to validate it also but seems its also not working.So my requirement is that how can i share a global variable across all scripts.Please let me know if there is a better approach.

Comment: See [`perldoc -q environment`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#I-%7Bchanged-directory%2C-modified-my-environment%7D-in-a-perl-script.-How-come-the-change-disappeared-when-I-exited-the-script%3F-How-do-I-get-my-changes-to-be-visible%3F)

Comment: This can now be done with [`Env::Modify`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Env::Modify)

Comment: @mob I did not know about that module. I'll re-open the question so you can answer it. We should then close the other related question with a link to this one.

Comment: If all your `system` calls are just invoking other perl scripts, a better approach is to turn your perl scripts into functions/libraries and call everything from a single perl process. Sharing environment variables between processes is overkill.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, child processes inherit a separate copy of the environment from their parent and changes made by the child do not propagate to the parent's environment.
[`Env::Modify`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Env::Modify) offers a workaround for this issue implementing the ["shell magic"](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#I-%7bchanged-directory%2c-modified-my-environment%7d-in-a-perl-script.-How-come-the-change-disappeared-when-I-exited-the-script%3f-How-do-I-get-my-changes-to-be-visible%3f) that the perlfaq talks about.

Typical usage:

```
use Env::Modify 'system',':bash';

print $ENV{FOO};                   #   ""
system("export FOO=bar");
print $ENV{FOO};                   #   "bar"
...
print $ENV{GIT_FLOW_ERROR_MSG};    #   ""
system("unpushed-changes");
print $ENV{GIT_FLOW_ERROR_MSG};    #   "true"
...
```

Answer (score 2):

As @mob mentioned there  are two ways to achieve this.`Env::Modify` or as a perl `lib`.So  i have chosen   `lib` over `Env::Modify`.because i want to run this script in every machine either explicitly `Env::Modify` package is installed or not.

I have written **Utils.pm** bundling both `unpush-changes` and `dependency-tree` functionalities and i  saved it under **/c/lib/My/Utils.pm**.

**Utils.pm**

```
package My::Utils;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter qw(import); 
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(build deploy);

sub build {
 system("mvn clean compile  -DskipTests")
 //Do  other things
}

sub deploy {
 //Do  things
}

1;
```

Then  i  used previously created library in my `pre-push` hook.

**pre-push**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename qw(dirname);
use Cwd  qw(abs_path);
use lib dirname(dirname abs_path $0) . '/lib'; 
use My::Utils qw(build deploy); // or use lib '/c/lib';

build();
deploy();
```

No  longer needs to worry about the `ENV` variables.[Reference](https://perlmaven.com/how-to-create-a-perl-module-for-code-reuse)

Comment: For this problem, this is definitely the way to go.