# How can I keep my environment variables between two calls to open?

Tags: perl, batch-file

I have a perl code running on Windows. This code calls `open` twice to execute two different batch files. The first one set an environment variable and the second one needs to use it. Unfortunately, the value sets to the variable is lost between the two calls.

Here is my Perl code.

```perl
my $hdl;
open($hdl, "set.bat |");
while(my $line = <$hdl>) {
    print("$line\n");
}
close($hdl);

open($hdl, "get.bat |");
while(my $line = <$hdl>) {
    print("$line\n");
}
close($hdl);
```

My `set.bat` file which sets the environment variable:

```
set VAR=20
echo %VAR%
```

And my `get.bat` which uses the environment variable:

```
echo %VAR%
```

When I run the perl code, here is the results:

```
>perl my_code.pl
>set VAR=20
>echo 20
20
>echo
ECHO is on.
```

We can see `set.bat` correctly sets the value of `VAR` but `get.bat` is unable to use it.

---

Also, if I run my two batch scripts in a row from the `cmd` prompt, I have the result I expect:

```
>set.bat
>set VAR=20
>echo 20
20
>get.bat
>echo 20
20
```

What can I do to let my second batch script to use my environment variable in my perl code?

Comment: Each process has its own environment variables that it inherits from its parent. You will need to set the env vars in the `perl` process or its parent, not a child

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `open` with a pipe creates a new process<sup>†</sup> and then your `set.bat` runs in that process and sets that environment variable in *that process*, which then exits.

Then `get.bat` runs in a yet different process and can see nothing of the first process.

However, they both inherit the environment of the process in which your Perl script is running. So you can set the needed environment in the script (via `%ENV`for instance) and then create a subprocess, and then that subprocess sees the environment.<sup>‡</sup>

On the other hand, you can run both shell scripts in the same subprocess, if that fits your purposes, via `system` for instance. Then one can `export` a variable into the environment, and after it's `source`-ed the next script to run will see it. Here is an example in Linux (can't do Windows  right now).

A command-line program ("one-liner")

```
perl -we'system("/bin/bash", "-c", q(source set.bat.sh; get.bat.sh))'
```

with the file `set.bat.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR=20
export VAR
```

and file `get.bat.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $VAR
```

The one-liner prints one line with `20`.

---

<sup>†</sup> The pipe-`open` is normally said to `fork` a process (see [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)), but on Windows that can only be emulated (via threads) as there is no native `fork`; see [perlfork](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfork.html). However, [perlport](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html) indicates that on Windows the 
pipe-`open` does create a subprocess (via Win32 API).

---

<sup>‡</sup>  A Linux example (can't test in Windows right now)

```
perl -we'$v = qx("set.bat.sh"); chomp $v; $ENV{VAR} = $v; system("get.bat.sh")'
```

with `set.bat.sh` file

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR=20
echo $VAR
```

and `get.bat.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $VAR
```

Since a subprocess cannot directly change the environment of its parent  the `set.bat.sh` prints `$VAR` to `STDOUT` and then its parent, the perl script, can read it from that stream (captured by `qx`) and set it in its own environment, which its next (grand-)child `get.bat.sh` inherits.  (A `system` forks a process, and in it another one is forked to run `get.bat.sh`. Environment is passed down.)

The weakness of this, of course, is that the perl script needs to know the name of the variable, `VAR`.  An improvement then would be for the `set.bat` to send the name itself along with the value.

Comment: @Pierre Updated with a way to do something like you ask

Comment: Probably run `.bat` files in `cmd`, though.

Comment: @tripleee Perhaps, right ... can't test now in Windows now and so I'd rather not guess :)

Answer (score 2):

The subprocesses are isolated from each other, and generally cannot affect the environments of each other or of the parent process.

For this limited example, maybe it is sufficient to reimplement part of the CMD language in Perl. If you only need to support a small subset, such as, say, assigning static strings to variables, it's not too hard:

```
if ($line ~ /^set\s+(\w+)=(\w+)$/) {
    $ENV{$1} = $2;
}
```

Perhaps use a different hash than `ENV` if you don't absolutely need to propagate these values to the environment.

Answer (score 2):

That's not easily done.
The reason is, that a child process normally inherits a **copy** of the parents process environment. Including environment variables.

See: [How to Share ENV Variables Among Perl Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44722935/how-to-share-env-variables-among-perl-scripts)

Comment: In the accepted answer, @mob talks about `Env::Modify`. Unfortunately, this package can't handle the calls to `open`. Is there an equivalent for this function?